# Drawable resources and NetBeans (Android Development)

Tags: android, netbeans, drawable

I'm newer in android development. And after using eclipse about 1 month... i hate this. I've setup NetBeans IDE for android development. It's fast, it's looks like cool and i like it. But have one trouble. I cant find how to use drawable resources (just like *R.drawable.icon*) :( . Can anyone help me?

PS: sry 4 my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file browser on the left hand side in NetBeans to open

YourProjectName -> res -> drawable and you will find your drawable files here. Also, Android provides different drawable folders to support multiple screen sizes, i.e : drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi. These are great if you wish to support your app on multiple screen sizes and don't want to scale the images using code (it makes them look ugly). Then you can just place different sizes of the same drawable image in these folders and android will automatically figure out which one to use!

Your English is quite decent in comparison to some of the drivel people post here.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler with updated version of NBAndroid (including NBAndroid Extensions). See some comments at http://www.nbandroid.org/2013/04/tuning-hyperlink-navigation.html